# Any ratios conventions on how Bolts are partially threaded vs shank left as is? Naming/ numbering/ notations to recognize offline/ find them online?

Tags: hardware-identification

Any ratios conventions on how Bolts are partially threaded vs shank left as is? Naming/ numbering/ notations to recognize offline/ find them online?

E.g. Looking to see if there commonly exists M6 - 18 /20 mm length 8/10mm threaded, rest 10mm shank?

PS: Nice guides, but no info on how the 2 aspects (thread vs not) get set up.

https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/measuring/notation.aspx

https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/Type-Chart.aspx

Comment: Are you asking about how much bolt thread must go into the nut to ensure a good hold? Is this about partially threaded bolts? Are you looking for nomenclature (naming convention) to be able to find a partially threaded bolt?

Comment: @FreeMan - The latter :)

Comment: "Partial thread" vs. "full thread". But this is probably more in the DIY.SE wheelhouse. Note that many, many online fastener sites will have an entire section dedicated to nomenclature. But linking to them here is a fool's errand because links will be dead in an internet minute. How much shank is unthreaded depends on application, and varies infinitely. Also, depends on "coarse" vs. "fine" thread, extra-fine, UNJC, UNJF, UNR, constant-pitch...

Comment: This is interesting information in itselt, *but why do you think you need it?* If it's in relation to your current desk project it's irrelevant I assure you.

Comment: I think you will not find  M6 without full thread Alex.

Comment: I found one bolt type for you in Google but large hex head and 0,51€ each!

Comment: @jdv - I saw a lot of sites, but there's no "specifics" on threaded vs unthreaded shank. It may vary a lot, but seems a bit random and no convention, nomenclature, notations, TAXONOMY or standards or method around them. Is there? I say M6 20 mm or 18mm it means specific. The partial has no "Add on" -10mm or 12mm etc.

Comment: @Graphus - Started off via desk, maybe its overkill & not big factor for desk :) now I'm curious to better understand this space so in the future when I search i have the "verbiage & nomenclature" down :)

Comment: @VolframK - :D I feeel like im sitting in a workshop with you guys. Wow! You are a master searcher - lots of love and thanks. Do share how you "filtered it out" :) from the online weeds.

Comment: @AlexS industries are a collection of ad hoc and competing official standards. Most of us don't care about that nomenclature if we aren't in the business of supplying or using some specific fastener in a commercial setting where it might really matter. It changes with use, as well. A thing you know as a specific bolt here will have a completely different name when supplied and used on military equipment. It is also domain specific; the transport truck biz has some specific standards they require that may not be share with other domains.

Comment: @AlexS at the end of the day, if you are a factory owner setting up some tooling, you negotiate with a fastener manufacturer to make what you want at the specs you need. The rest of us just get to choose from a rainbow of standard issue and left-overs from those factories jobs. There may be one or more standards for describing how much unthreaded shank is needed for some application where an engineer has determine they need the strength and to fit just right in a widget. Those of us in the home shop would just describe it as a length & search for the closest. Or you make your own, if possible.

Comment: "Standards are great; everyone should have one."

Comment: The best answer might be: "metric fastener standards" in your favourite search engine, and adjust from there. There may even be a ISO standard that is not implemented completely by anyone, and probably more than one competing industry specific standard. Along with the usual not-quite-standard MILSPEC stuff. And then historical ad hoc stuff. Even metric is old enough to have accrued some ad hoc cruft over the decades.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm actually amazed that @VolframK found any M6 bolts (much less at these lengths!) which were only partially threaded. For a given bolt type and size shorter lengths *usually* won't have any plain shank, while beyond a certain length (e.g. 35mm and up) they are partially threaded, like [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0570/0209/8865/products/LRG_DSC01082.jpg). I've never been clear on why (what the supposed advantage is, in service) but I wonder if it's merely to save on manufacturing time since the nut generally goes right at the end, or pretty close.

Comment: @jdv there is an [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/) for everything!

Comment: @Graphus AIUI, the unthreaded portion of the bolt sort-of, more-or-less makes it as though you drilled an actual clearance hole in the first part of the wood you're connecting. Since the strength of a screw is in its clamping ability, threads in the top piece won't actually pull the 2 boards tight together. If there is a full clearance hole (or lack of threads), tightening the screw _will_ close any gap between the boards. Of course, I might just have made that up long enough ago for my brain to have accepted it as true...

Comment: @Graphus - V has superpowers :) We ought to pray to him for some :) PS: Not sure, but I read that plain shank > threads at points of high shear, esp if that section is not threaded but just "clamping/ holding" a layer in between.

Comment: @FreeMan I am sure lots of nuanced micro ME & Material Science & Physics goes into figuring and making them in all these varieties.

Comment: There are plenty of uses of fully threaded fasteners where strains are high, including an element of shear. And for your desktop attachment there's no expectation of high shear, so even if there were a significant strength advantage in machine screws as small as M6 it's not needed here. Just to reiterate something said previously, the norm for attaching tabletops is normal wood screws; these are generally smaller than M6, inherently hold less well, *and* (historically for sure) were definitely weaker (could even be brass and not any kind of steel)...... but despite all this, they did the job.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the long discussion in comments:

As you've discovered in your searching, there is no standard naming convention for the amount of unthreaded portion of a screw or bolt. There is probably no standard amount of unthreaded portion between manufacturers, and likely not standard within a single manufacturer when comparing screws to bolts and different styles of bolts.

Unless you're an engineer designing and ordering a *very* large quantity of bolts that need to meet specific requirements for the assembly of a specific item, you simply buy a screw or bolt that meets your requirement of length, diameter, and pitch (particularly for machine screws or bolts/nuts). If it happens to have an unthreaded portion, it does, if it doesn't, it doesn't.

And, as always, there's an [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927) for everything:

[image: XKCD #927 - standards proliferation]